# display data on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 buttons `Start` And `Walk Away`. I want that initially the walk away button should not appear but on the click of start button the walk away button should appear ( I do not want to use toggle).

I have 2 issues:

1) On the click of start button i am able to hide and display the second button but i am not able to hide the button initially.
2) after the Walk Away button appears on the click of Start button i wish that the walk away button should hide automatically after 2 minutes. i am not able to do so

At present the code that is running properly is . Code at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/saytq920/1/)

```js
$("#start").click(function () {
    $("#walkaway").show();
});
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="start" value="Submit">Start</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="walkaway" value="Submit">Walk Away</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the button initially use CSS:

```
#walkaway {
    display: none;
}
```

To hide button after 2 seconds use `delay`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start").click(function () {
        $("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/saytq920/2/

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="walkaway" value="Submit" style="display:none">Walk Away</button>
```

Comment: I hate `inline styles`

Answer (score 0):

use this using pure jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#walkaway").hide();

    $("#start").click(function () {
        $("#walkaway").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#walkaway").hide();
        }, 120000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To initially hide the start button you could use css and set it to:

```
#walkaway {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
#walkaway {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

depending on your layout and what you want to achieve.

To hide the button after 2 minutes you need to use `delay`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start").click(function () {
       $("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

delay takes milliseconds as an argument, so 120 seconds = 2 minutes = 120.000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use set timeOut function as following code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#walkaway").hide();

    $("#start").click(function () {
        $("#walkaway").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#walkaway").hide();
        }, 2000); // <-- change to 120000 for 2 minutes
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="start" value="Submit">Start</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="walkaway" value="Submit">Walk Away</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    test = function () {
        $("#walkaway").show();
    };

    test1 = function () {
        $("#walkaway").hide();
    };

    test1();

    $("#start").click(function () {
        test();
        setTimeout(test1, 120000);
    });

});
```